# Multiple RangeOfString in one variable

Tags: swift

Is there any solution for me to do like code below?

```
let tmp: NSString = data.status
        let tmp1: NSString = data.process
 let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch) && tmp1.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
        return range.location != NSNotFound
```

I am doing this because I want to search for more than one field.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

[image]You can Try this

```
if data.status.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) || data.process.contains(searchText) {
    return true
}else {
    return false
}
```

Comment: can i still have my variable range by doing so? sorry for asking silly question because i just touched swift for 3 days only

Comment: It will only check whether the search string contain in status or process

Comment: i get value of type 'String' has no member 'lowercased'

Comment: @DaveCruise Which version of swift you are using

Comment: I Have added a screen shot here

Comment: I did almost the same. I think my current swift is swift2.0

Comment: filtered = allItems.filter({ data in
            let tmp = data.status
            if(tmp.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()))
            {
            let tmp: NSString = data.process
            let range = tmp.rangeOfString(searchText, options: NSStringCompareOptions.CaseInsensitiveSearch)
            return range.location != NSNotFound
            }
        })                          This is what I am having now.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the range, you should use `RegularExpression` instead

```
import Foundation

let pattern = "search"

let regexp = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: NSRegularExpression.Options())
let string = "String to search in search"
regexp.enumerateMatches(in: string, options: NSRegularExpression.MatchingOptions(), range: NSMakeRange(0, string.characters.count), using:  { (result, flags, stop) in

    if result?.range != nil {
        print("Range is \(result!.range.location)-\(result!.range.length)")
    }
})
```